# How to import manually a module on vuejs without npm?

Tags: vue.js, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to use  facebook login button ,but the " npm install --save vue-facebook-login-component" stay stuck . How can i import the module manualy?

Comment: You can clone the repo under the node_modules but I would not recommend it. Try to find out why npm is getting stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by "stay stuck"? Is there an error message?

Comment: @AndreiSavin its start to download , and its stuck at :            extract:vue-facebook-signin-button: verb lock using C:\Users\mabik\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-50bd06186d17a1ee.lock for C:\Users\m